# Find probability given a binomial and a normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

$X$~$Bin(n,p),Y_n$~$N(μ,\sigma^2)$

Where X is the number of trials taking place, and $Y_n$ is the amount of time the $n$th trial takes (independent of other trials).

$Z$ is a new random variable that denotes the total time of all trials taking place.

I believe $Z$ to be $\sum\limits_{n=1}^X Y_n$.

The problem is I have no idea where to start when finding the probability for situations with $Z$. eg. $P(Z<60)$

Do I find the joint p.d.f. first? $f(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$?

Any hints are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You can use the [law of total expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) and the [law of total variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) to find the mean and variance of $Z$: for example $E[Z]=np\mu$.

Comment: @Henry Thanks! I have figured the expected value and variance too. Can Z be described to follow a specific distribution using E[Z] and Var[Z]? I was thinking poisson approximation but this wouldn't work since n is arbitrary in size here.

Comment: You might use a normal approximation, though I doubt it will work well unless $np$ is much bigger than $1$ and $\sqrt{np}\sigma$ is much bigger than $\mu$.  Note that you also need $\mu$ much bigger than $\sigma$ to avoid too many negative trial times.

Answer (score 0):

Try characteristic function: we know the CF for $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is
$$\phi(t)=\exp\left\{i\mu t-\dfrac{1}{2}\sigma^2t^2\right\}$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[e^{itZ}]&=\mathbb{P}
[X=0]+\mathbb{E}\left[\exp
\left\{it\sum\nolimits_{j=1}^kY_j\right\}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{X\geq 1}\right]\\
&=\mathbb{P}
[X=0]+\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^n\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1}_{X=k}\cdot\prod\nolimits_{j=1}^k
\exp\{it Y_j\}\right]\\
&=\mathbb{P}[X=0]+\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^n\mathbb{P}[X=k]\phi^k(t)
\hspace{10pt}\text{(by independence of $X$, $Y_1$, $Y_2$, $\cdots$)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\mathbb{P}[X=k]\phi^k(t)\ =\ \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k\phi^k(t)(1-p)^{n-k}\\
\end{align}
Then we can recover the density of $Z$ from CF. The computation is a little complicated, but this is the only method I know. Maybe some other users have better idea!